# Apache2 Graceful Loads Different php.ini

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I have an apache server running Apache/mod_php.

On Fresh start and when using sudo service apache2 restart the correct php.ini file is loaded:

[image]

Doing a graceful reload of apache i.e "sudo service apache2 graceful" results in php loading a different php.ini (which is non-existing on filesystem):
[image]

What could be causing this and any ideas on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

From http://php.net/php.ini:

> Note:
>   The Apache web server changes the directory to root at startup, causing PHP to attempt to read php.ini from the root filesystem if it exists.

Are you sure /php.ini does not exist?

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for the response. Indeed I have verified that this file is non-existent. That issue aside any idea why a different php.ini file will be loaded on a graceful v full restart of apache?

Comment: It re-reads the Apache/PHP configs. I don't suppose you have a different environment on graceful restart to a full restart? Are you chroot()ing at all? We would need to see more of your Apache/PHP config I think.